# Errors and Warning in importing and running INET framework

Tags: omnet++, inet

im having problems in importing INET built-in examples. Im new to omnet++ and INET framework and feeling unfamiliar to these things. FYI, im using windows 10 64 bits, omnet++ 5.6.2 and INET 4.2.2. I import the INET using the 'install simulation model' feature of the Omnet++. After it got imported, a lot of warnings appeared (as shown in the attached picture).[list of warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iJyo.png)

Anyone can help me to get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Those warnings might be false positive. Sometimes it is not possible to figure out what parameters are valid without actually running the simulation because some types are determined only during runtime. This means that the IDE tries its best to figure out if a parameter is valid or not, often it generates warnings that are in fact not problems at all during runtime.

Just ignore them :(

Comment: i will tried to run it and see whether it can be run successfully or not. Thanks.